# Файлы ini в приложение на Python

Tags: python, pyqt5, ini

Я использую файлы .ini для сохранение настроек в приложение ( приложение создано на питоне PyQt5 и использую его на платформе wondows ) и хочу интегрировать егиэо на ОС линукс, так вот в чем суть - могу ли я использовать эти файлы в Линукс ? Если нет то какие есть вариации ? Буду очень благодарен !

Comment: Можете использовать без проблем, а будут проблемы заходите :)

Comment: ini-файлы ничем не отличаются от любых других файлов на любой системе

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В линуксе (в тех файловых системах, что я знаю) файлы не имеют расширений, это просто часть названия файла, так что можно что угодно там писать (в рамках допустимых символов и длины).